# How to create a recursive method to compare two values?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, openframeworks

I'm generating random values in a for loop and I would like to test if the next about to be generated value is not near any of the other values, if so I would like to position it outside a tolerance radius, this is what I have so far:

```
int spacing = 30;
// create a bunch of random points
for ( int i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBER_OF_DOTS; i++ )
{
    ofVec2f point( ofRandom(spacing, ofGetWidth() - (spacing + spacing)), ofRandom( spacing, ofGetHeight() - (spacing + spacing)) );

    // Loop trough previously create points and check its distance
    for ( int j = 0; j < dots.size(); j++ )
    {
        ofVec2f testPoint = dots[j];
        float minDistance = 20.0f;
        // If the point is too close move it to a random point around it
        if ( point.distance( testPoint ) < minDistance )
        {
            point.x += cos( ofRandom( TWO_PI ) ) + minDistance;
            point.y += sin( ofRandom( TWO_PI ) ) + minDistance;
        }
    }
    dots.push_back( point );
}
```

Where **`dots`** is **`vector<ofVec2f> dots;`**
Is not perfect, because the new calculated point doesn't take into account near previously created dots, so I think a recursive method can help me solve the problem.

Comment: could you include `ofVec2f ` to your code?

Comment: @philippe here is a reference for ofVec2f http://www.openframeworks.cc/documentation/math/ofVec2f.html hope that helps

Comment: You could re-start your checking of all points (instead of continuing from where you are in the loop) after you select a new point to ensure this new location is also not in the vicinity of any of the previously checked points.  Note that this approach can end up taking a long time to calculate if you have many points and/or the currently existing points cover most of the available area

Comment: This gets really tricky when you get anywhere near the space filling limit. This problem is like adding marbles to a box (with a sticky floor so they don't roll). When you're close to having filled the box. How do you prove that there are no more points where a marble might fit?!

Comment: Might I add a different solution? What do you need the points for, and do you absolutely need the number of accepted points to be a certain value? If not, then jut generate N points, and then go through the list and remove any that overlap with any of the previously accepted points. You'll end up with (N-x) points where x gets larger and larger the closer you get to filling the space, but will never be larger than N. If all you want to do is to, say, paint some polka-dots then this may be just fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [geometric hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_hashing) algorithm to check if the newly created point is closer than  "minDistance" to any other previously created point.
A good article that describes this method when applied to protein conformations can be found [here](http://www.inesc-id.pt/pt/indicadores/Ficheiros/4858.pdf).